# android lollipop - setentertransition() for fragment not working properly on exiting

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

While replacing fragment, I am using Slide animation available for android lollipop version. It works as expected for this particular replacement, but on pressing back button it first pops back current fragment & then reverse of enter animation (slide out) is executed.

```
private void replaceContentFrameByFragment(Fragment replaceBy, String replaceByFragmentTag) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            slide.setDuration(1000);
            replaceBy.setEnterTransition(slide);
    }
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, replaceBy, replaceByFragmentTag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

So, how to force fragment to pop back only after reverse animation of slide is finished? I noticed that activity has method finishAfterTransition() provided. Is there something similar for frgament?

Comment: read more about transitions here: www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-content-transitions-in-depth-part2.html

Comment: Adding separate return transition also shows the same behaviour.     Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
slide.setDuration(1000);     replaceBy.setEnterTransition(slide);
          
slide = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
slide.setDuration(1000);
replaceBy.setReturnTransition(slide);

Comment: Can you post a screen capture of the behavior you are witnessing (it is hard to tell what you are describing exactly). Android Studio has a screen capture tool that might be handy.

Comment: When popping, your exiting fragment executes the return transition and your entering fragment executes the reenter transition. The allowEnterTransitionOverlap and allowReturnTransitionOverlap let you control whether the two transitions happen simultaneously or overlapping. You can create a new Transition that just blinks the view back in if that's what you want, or use Fade as the reenter transition along with allowReturnTransitionOverlap.

Comment: @AlexLockwood please check this demo video: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/n2obyx/8). When I press back button, it overlaps animation on exiting fragment and first fragment existing in the back stack (having 2 buttons - login & sign up)

Comment: @GeorgeMount My 1st fragment has no transition effects applied. I have only 2nd fragment with both the enter & return transitions. Hence I think there is no question of overlapping transitions. For better clarification, you can check small video posted here: [http://tinypic.com/r/n2obyx/8](http://tinypic.com/r/n2obyx/8)

Comment: I see what you mean now. It appears that the background of your leaving fragment has been removed and the transition may be skipping frames. I'm not sure what would cause this problem -- the containing View should automatically be considered a transitionGroup because the background exists. Try setting a background on some of the elements and see how far it gets you. There may be something weird with the fragment's outer element background. Have you tried this outside the emulator?

Comment: @GeorgeMount No, I am still to get the real device for testing this. But anyways, due to above issue for now I have decided to use customAnimations() function provided in FragmentTransaction class.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, onReturn from Fragment B -> A, Fragment B seem to be doing an extra slide transition. To get around it, I put in a fade transition for `setReturnTransition()` of a shorter time than the slide which looks quite good (as it dissolves into previous fragment). The code for this is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Slide slideRight = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
    slideRight.setDuration(200);
    fragment.setEnterTransition(slideRight);
    Fade fade = new Fade();
    fade.setDuration(100);
    fragment.setReturnTransition(fade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with roughly the same pattern and was able to get around it by posting my fragments transition:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        page.setEnterTransition(new Slide());
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.root_layout, page, "current")
                .commit();
    }
});
```

Not sure why this resolves the issue (or if this is the absolute correct solution), but it worked for me.